# Automating a button click in Netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

I'm currently working on a project and the client wants us to generate a pdf report and send it as a scheduled email.
We have managed to generate the report through a button by creating a custom record and deploying a user event and client script to call a suitelet where we are using XML to pdf conversion to generate the report.

Getting to the main part. We now have to automate the email sending process in which the report pdf is attached. The problem is the client wants the entire process to happen without clicking the button to generate the pdf.

The problem is I don't know how to automate the creation of the PDF without the button click as I'm still new to netsuite and suitescript.

If there is any way to automatically run this suitelet report please let me know. Once we are able to generate the report without the button click we could probably use a scheduled script to send the email and set the pdf as an attachment.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run a scheduled map/reduce script.  Suggest you lookup this type of script in the help centre.

It can execute actions for each record returned by a saved search.